# checkboxes in dropdown list without javascript [html5]

Tags: html, forms

I'd like to know if is it possible to make a dropdown checklist without using javascript.

Using balise like hidden (to hide the checkboxes) and unhide them with onclick (or something like that)
if is it possible, someone can show me how ?

There is an sample of dropdown list :
https://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Comment: What is a dropdown checkbox?

Comment: Something like this : https://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Comment: That is only achievable by using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as andershagbard says That is only achievable by using JavaScript